# RecyclerView won't update after a restart/crash

Tags: java, android, sockets

So I am working on an app that is involving sockets. Multiple strings is sent through the socket, the receiving end receives it, and updates the `RecyclerView` correspondingly. It's working fine, that is until the app crashes / restarts. I do not know what happens, but there's this app called XRecorder on Play Store and everytime I use the screenshot function- my app restarts. Now when I send a message through the socket, it receives the message but it doesn't update the RecyclerView? The `Toast` appears that's why I know it is received. And it updates as well when I call `removeItem()`

Here's my code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    serverAsync.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}

private class ServerAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
                while (true) {
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    isConnected = client.isConnected();

                    if (isConnected) {
                       try {
                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   updateStatusUI();
                               }
                           });

                           Entry entry = new Entry();
                           String inputLine;
                           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                           while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                               String message = inputLine;
                               sb.append(message);
                               entry.add(sb.toString());
                           }

                           //READ NEW ENTRIES
                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   splitOrder(entry);
                                   saveArrayList();
                               }
                           });

                           in.close();
                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   entryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In has closed :" + client.getRemoteSocketAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   updateStatusUI();
                               }
                           });

                       } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("TEST", e.getMessage(), e);
                       }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Client :" + client.getRemoteSocketAddress()+" has DISCONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateStatusUI();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("UHE", e.getMessage(), e);

            }
            return null;
        }
    }

public void removeItem(int position) {
     entryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I've tried resetting the adapter for the `RecyclerView`, but it just wouldn't work. I also noticed that everytime I the app crashes and restart, I am getting the `java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)`

Pointing to the creation of my serverSocket `(serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort)`

Could this be the reason why the RecyclerView won't update? The ArrayList updates just fine with the incoming messages, but not the view.

Comment: Sounds like you create this thread multiple times, and the second time the socket is still running so you can't bind the port to it so you crash because it is never stopped or anything.

Comment: I only start it at startup. And I don't think that that's the cause for the RecyclerView not to update? The ArrayList updates just fine, but the RecyclerView wouldn't.

Comment: The BindException appears after the crash and when the app restarts.